# Change microphone equalizer on iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, hardware-recommendation, voice

I'd like to give a favorable impression during phone/audio calls by adjusting the tone of my voice.
Are there any software solutions for iOS to change the tone of voice coming into the microphone?
If not, what accessories would you use to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt changing the EQ on a phone call would make much difference at all. Phone audio is very limited in both bandwidth & quality, as it's designed purely for intelligibility not 'HiFi'.

Comment: @Tetsujin While difference may be unnoticeable in phone calls, the changes in quality are noticable in HiFi audio use, like voice messages on messenger apps or video calls

Comment: Not really. What exactly are you trying to achieve anyway? Over anything telephonic, a bit of EQ isn't going to change the 'tone' of your voice; I've tried it over such as Skype & Zoom on a Mac where I can easily insert audio FX in the signal chain. I've tested right up to microphones costing £2500. It really makes very, very little difference. [I'm a professional audio engineer, btw, which is why I have easy access to very high quality mics.]

Comment: Interesting. Sometimes I watch live streams on YouTube where participants use external audio equipment to achieve high voice quality. That indicates that getting good voice quality is possible. [Sweet job perks, by the way.]

Comment: If only it was a perk - I had to buy them all myself ;) You will hear the distinction on a higher quality stream, just not on a phone call or any modern equivalent of one.